# What does a Promise guarded by a catch() return?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an asynchronous function that is called at the beginning of my code, and only when it is done further things can happen. It would typically be something like

```js
const initialCheck = () => {
  return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(r => {
      // do things
      return r
    })
}

const actualStuff = () => {
  console.log('hello')
}

initialCheck()
  .then(r => {
    actualStuff()
  })
```

The goal of this initial check is to make sure that the HTTP endpoint (`https://reqres.in/api/users`) is actually reachable. It should therefore account for a connection issue and my solution was to `catch()` the possible error:

```js
const initialCheck = () => {
  return fetch('https://thissitedoesnotexistihopeatleast')
    .then(r => {
      // do things when the endpoint is available
      return r
    })
    .catch(err => {
    // do something when the endpoint is not availble
    // nothing is returned
    })
}

const actualStuff = () => {
  console.log('hello')
}

initialCheck()
  .then(r => {
    actualStuff()
  })
```

**My question: why does the code above work?**

`catch()` is executed (and the `then()` in that unction is not), it does not return anything, and despite that `.then(r => {actualStuff()})` outputs what is expected (`hello` on the console).

What does that `then()` actually receives? (that I do not `return`)

Comment: Your `.catch()` has no return value inside it so it returns `undefined` which means that the promise chain will resolve with an `undefined` resolved value.  This is analogous to `try/catch` where if you "handle" the catch and don't rethrow, the exception is done.  Similarly, with a promise, the rejection turns into a resolved promise if you don't rethrow or return a rejected promise from the `.catch()`.

Comment: You could try logging the return value to see what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.catch` chained onto a Promise will result in a Promise that:

- resolves with the value returned from the `.catch`, if the `.catch` returns normally
- rejects with the error, if the `.catch` itself throws an error

So

```
const chainedPromise = somePromise.catch(() => {
  // no errors here
  // nothing returned
})
```

If the `.catch` definitely doesn't throw, then `chainedPromise` will definitely resolve (and not reject), and since nothing is returned, the `chainedPromise` will resolve to `undefined`.

So

```
initialCheck()
  .then(r => {
    actualStuff()
  })
```

works because `initialCheck` returns a Promise that resolves (to `undefined`).

If you returned something from the `.catch`, and the `.catch` was entered into, you'd see it onto `.then`s chained onto it later:

```js
const initialCheck = () => {
  return fetch('https://doesnotexist')
    .catch(() => {
      return 'foo';
    });
}

const actualStuff = (r) => {
console.log(r);
  console.log('r is foo:', r === 'foo')
}

initialCheck()
  .then(r => {
    actualStuff(r);
  })
```